# Is the RSECNOTE tool used for the ABAP and/or JAVA stack?

Tags: java, abap, sap-basis

Does the RSECNOTE tool display security note information for the ABAP and/or JAVA stack?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it's only concerned with the ABAP part.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to identify OSS notes which can be implemented (usually via transaction SNOTE) into the ABAP stack.

The RSECNOTE tool creates the detailed evaluation of the required security-relevant notes or Hot News in the system to be analyzed.

You can use transaction ST13 to start the tool RSECNOTE or you can also start the tool as the report RSECNOTE by using transaction SA38.

The RSECNOTE tool is part of the software component ST-A/PI.

For more information please see Note 888889 - Automatic checks for security notes using RSECNOTE.

Also see http://www.sapdev.co.uk/security/security_check.htm for more information.